# Average (/2) of each row in ONE column in R

Tags: r, mean

```
DF
    ID B C D
  1  A  1  1  3
  2  B  2  3  1
  3  C  1  1  1
  4  D  3  1  1
  5  E  1  0  0
```

Given a dataframe such the one mentioned above, how can I quickly calculate the means for each row in one column and store them in another column of the dataframe? For example the average of column B would be: 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1,5, 0.5.
And is it possible to have a function that does it automatically for several columns at once?

Comment: What is the expected `rowMeans(DF[-1])`

Comment: Do you need `DF['B']/DF[2,2]`, but it is not 0.05, it would be 0.5

Comment: Holy s... I got lost in translation, sorry people it's easy, I just meant something different. thanks for the sassiness. Well deserved

Comment: If you could update your post, it would be easier to understand thanks

Comment: @akrun yeah yeah I meant 0.5. Just used to write down 0.05 too often

Comment: can you check my solution below.  I showed two options.  First one, was based on matching the 'B' from 'ID' column to gret the corresponding value of 'B' column to divide thee 'B'.  Second, by a constant value 2

Comment: thanks that was really helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option is to get the matching row element from 'ID' to divide the column with the value

```
f1 <- function(dat, colNm) transform(dat, 
       newCol = dat[[colNm]]/dat[match(colNm, ID), colNm])
f1(DF, 'B')
#   ID B C D newCol
#1  A 1 1 3    0.5
#2  B 2 3 1    1.0
#3  C 1 1 1    0.5
#4  D 3 1 1    1.5
#5  E 1 0 0    0.5
```

---

If it is to divide by a constant value, then just do

```
DF[-1] <- DF[-1]/2
```

#### data

```
DF <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), B = c(1L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 1L), C = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 0L), D = c(3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5"))
```